# What is better way to save the session id in actions.py file cache or slots in rasa chatbot

Tags: python, authentication, caching, chatbot, rasa

I am using RASA framework and using frontend to launch chatbot icon .
When user logins to website, session is started and session id, token etc is saved and passed to custom actions of actions.py .
Whenever page is refreshed, new session id is generated and it is again passed to actions.py file.
Below is the part of code from actions.py which is used to get data from front end.

```
from helpers import fetch_acdata

class WelcomeAction(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "grtaction"

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        acdata = fetch_acdata(tracker=tracker)
        name = fetch_acdata["sender"] if "sender" in acdata .keys() else ''
        dispatcher.utter_message(template="ug", **tracker.slots, user_name=name)
        return [AllSlotsReset()]
```

Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to save the session id from chatbot server. You can create simple flask app to save your user related information and let your flask talk to chatbot server directly. Calling a chatbot endpoint from front-end directly wouldn't be the best case.

Comment: I have to fetch database information  from backend based on session id which is sent from front end angular to actions.py. So, session id is needed . Lets say 10 times page was refreshed in last 2 hours, it will provide 10 session id. All need to be save in some cache in python actions itself.